# Get NSManagedObject from NSSet

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsset

I have `NSSet` containing `NSManagedObjects` from `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` notification.
**The problem is that:** I want to get the type of `NSManagedObject` in NSSet.
For example, is it `Album`, `User` or any other `NSManagedObject`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have a managed object called `entity`, then use the following code to retrieve the name of the managed object:

```
NSManagedObjectID *objectID = [entity objectID];
NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [objectID entity];
NSString *name = [entityDescription name];
```

For clarity I've declared variables on each line, but of course you could also write `[[[entity objectID] entity] name]`

I hope this is what you're looking for.

Comment: I think it must be `NSString *name = [entityDescription name];`